# pgfplots import data from table with comma as decimal separator

Tags: tables, pgfplots, punctuation

I am trying to plot data from data files which are using the comma as decimal separator instead of a point (as is normal in SI style (French version): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Examples_of_use ). However, even after excessive search I cannot find an option that would actually tell pgfplots to read the table with the comma as decimal separator. Minimal (not) working sample:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,version=last,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            width=0.9\textwidth,
            height=0.5\textheight,
            xlabel={Standardweg~[mm]},
            ylabel={Standardkraft~[N]},
            grid=major,
            ]
        \addplot table[x=Standardweg, y=Standardkraft] {Messwerte.TRA};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Messwerte.TRA:

```
Standardweg  Standardkraft
0,000000000000e+000  1,960904836655e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     3,081407308578e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     4,164415359497e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     5,441759109497e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     6,443712234497e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     7,598009109497e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     8,951524734497e+000
-6,029571522959e-001     1,002574348450e+001
-2,349615044750e-004     1,122496223450e+001
-2,349615044750e-004     1,252183723450e+001
```

On compilation, I get the error:
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '-2,349615044750e-004' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ',349615044750e-004'.. for every single number in the .TRA-file.

I know that I could find and replace every , with a . in the files, but that is not an option considering the amount of files I have to evaluate.

Also, I tried stuff like `/pgf/number format/use comma`, `set decimal separator={{,}}`, `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2,use period}` and `use comma`, but none of that helped and I am pretty much running out of options. The documentation for pgfplots did not give any other ideas, either.

So: How do I convince pgfplots to actually read the comma as decimal separator and to not search for the point?

Comment: What about opening the file in a text editor and replacing commas with dots by the search&replace function?

Comment: @Thorsten-Donig: As I mentioned: I know about that option, but it does not help considering the fact that I have multiple files and this just wouldn't do.

Comment: There seems to be no other option. Perhaps a script could automate this process.

Comment: @locutus: The PGF math parser is hard-wired to look for periods as decimal separators, teaching it to also accept commas would be a lot of work. The options you found merely concern how numbers are printed, but not how they are parsed. I would recommend replacing the comma with a period in the data files, like Thorsten said. If you're on Linux, you can use a `sed` one-liner: `sed -i 's/,/\./g' *.dat` will replace all commas with periods in all files ending in `.dat`.

Comment: Or, slightly more robust, use `sed -i 's/\([[:digit:]]\),\([[:digit:]]\)/\1\.\2/g' *.dat` to only replace commas that are surrounded by digits.

Comment: If you are on Wind0ws, you can use the [GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Jake Also we can start with string type and create two more columns by stripping comma and replacing with dots. But that's super inefficient. :)

Comment: @percusse: I highjacked your idea. Sorry!

Comment: @Jake I mailed you my IBAN number :P

Comment: I have just implemented this in PGF CVS, i.e. some future version will offer an option `read comma as period` (it will advertise it in error messages as well). It is off by default because I anticipated problems with the math parser (which might have other meansings for comma).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Any news about this feature?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé the feature is available in PGF, but since there has been no PGF release since 3.0.0, it is unavailable on CTAN. I don't know for sure if there is an unstable PGF build which contains it. It is used with `\pgfmathprintnumber[read comma as period]{1234,56}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With an uptodate pgf/TikZ version (current on CTAN is 3.0.1a) it is now possible to use the new key `/pgf/number format/read comma as period`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,version=last,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=0.9\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textheight,
    xlabel={Standardweg~[mm]},
    ylabel={Standardkraft~[N]},
    grid=major,
  ]
  \addplot table[
    x=Standardweg, y=Standardkraft,
    /pgf/number format/read comma as period% <---
    ] {
    Standardweg  Standardkraft
    0,000000000000e+000  1,960904836655e+000
    -2,349615044750e-004     3,081407308578e+000
    -2,349615044750e-004     4,164415359497e+000
    -2,349615044750e-004     5,441759109497e+000
    -2,349615044750e-004     6,443712234497e+000
    -2,349615044750e-004     7,598009109497e+000
    -2,349615044750e-004     8,951524734497e+000
    -6,029571522959e-001     1,002574348450e+001
    -2,349615044750e-004     1,122496223450e+001
    -2,349615044750e-004     1,252183723450e+001
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in the comments, the easiest thing to do is probably to replace the commas with periods in the data files (for example using `sed -i 's/\([[:digit:]]\),\([[:digit:]]\)/\1\.\2/g' *.dat` on Linux).

However, as Percusse points out, an alternative is to use the comma as an additional column separator by setting `white space chars={{,},\ }`, thereby splitting each number into two different columns, and merging them using

```
x expr=\thisrowno{0}.\thisrowno{1},
y expr=\thisrowno{2}.\thisrowno{3}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,version=last,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            width=0.9\textwidth,
            height=0.5\textheight,
            xlabel={Standardweg~[mm]},
            ylabel={Standardkraft~[N]},
            grid=major,
            ]
        \addplot table[x=Standardweg, y=Standardkraft, white space chars={{,},\ },
            x expr=\thisrowno{0}.\thisrowno{1},     y expr=\thisrowno{2}.\thisrowno{3}] {
        Standardweg  Standardkraft
0,000000000000e+000  1,960904836655e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     3,081407308578e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     4,164415359497e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     5,441759109497e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     6,443712234497e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     7,598009109497e+000
-2,349615044750e-004     8,951524734497e+000
-6,029571522959e-001     1,002574348450e+001
-2,349615044750e-004     1,122496223450e+001
-2,349615044750e-004     1,252183723450e+001
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay. This indeed solves the problem. Not the cleanest solution but still better than altering all the files (and also altering all the files that might still come!). The actual files have a few more columns, but that should easily be coverable. I guess I will go by your solution. Thanks a lot!