# Parsing CSV with comma as decimal separator in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How can I plot data from CSV file when comma is separator of decimal part?

Part of my CSV file:

```
U f(U)
0 6,12323399573677E-016
0,1257 1,2536924115
0,2514 2,4876019375
```

I've tried this trick but it doesn't help me.

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2,use comma}
```

Is any elegant solution of my problem (without replacing characters in data file)?

Here is how I generate the plot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, ]
\addplot[blue] table {wykres-2.1-przyklad 3.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: That looks like you have white space as the delimiter, so it is not a comma-separated values file... Can you give an example of what your final purpose is? BTW, Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Try with `,use comma,col sep=space`.

Comment: @darthbith I've mean that comma is separator between decimal and rest in float number. Normally in computers dot is use as separator for example "1.2222" but in my country we use comma, so it should look like "1,2222". I've data from spreadsheet and I must use it in my Latex document to plot.

Comment: @HarishKumar Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/col sep'

Comment: @bigben I got what you mean, what I meant was what Harish Kumar pointed out - your column separators are spaces, not commas, so it is not a CSV file. Can you nonetheless provide an example of how you're plotting the data so we can try fixes? Also, see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159638/32374

Comment: @darthbith
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \begin{axis}[

  xlabel={$x$},

  ylabel={$y$},

  ]

  \addplot[blue] table {wykres-2.1-przyklad 3.csv};

 \end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: `use comma` won't work. Separate your data to integer and decimal part and concatenate in a separate column as text in Excel with a period char.

Comment: @bigben Thanks! According to this comment on the question I linked before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159638/pgfplots-import-data-from-table-with-comma-as-decimal-separator#comment477312_159638 the option to use comma as decimal separator is added to the developers version of PGF but has not made it out into the mainstream yet. So as percusse says, you have to work around it.

Comment: @darthbith and HarishKumar After all, thanks for your help.