# Why is the scaled ticks label placed incorrectly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

See the following example, created by `matlab2tikz`. I removed a lot of lines to simplify the problem.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=0.99266\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
xmin=0,
xmax=120,
ymin=-100000,
ymax=50000,
]
\addplot [color=red,solid,line width=2.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
 1  -86255.5783320323\\
2   -74068.0571042609\\
4   -57710.3221301868\\
 105    10939.2665934164\\
 106    11754.7103271752\\
 110    15903.9005100491\\
111 17245.0672141506\\
};  
\addlegendentry{A21};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

This creates the following pic:
[image]

Why is the `10^5` placed incorrectly? Nothing in the reference could help so far...

```
Package: pgfplots 2014/08/04 v1.11 Data Visualization (1.11-3-g4c99d7a)
```

TeXLive 2014.

edit: Here now an MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
  ticklabel style={% gilt für x und y
/pgf/number format/.cd,
use comma,% Komma als Dezimaltrenner
1000 sep = {}% keine Tausendertrennung 
  }}
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}
\input{2nd.tikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Without the pgfplotsset instruction, the problem does not occur. But I need the comma separation. Is there a  simpler way of having commas instead of points, like a localization of pgfplots?

Comment: Must be that `\figurewidth,height` stuff. I don't see any problems other than your pgfplots version is older than 1.11

Comment: I added the version information. Removing \figurewidth/height doesn't change anything -- and why this is bad?

Comment: @Sebastian Please provide a complete MWE from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. This is especially important, because if you don't tell `pgfplots` which version you want to use (with e.g. `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}`), it defaults to a version that might have this issue. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: With a standard preamble and your `pgfplots` problem I do not get this problem.

Comment: No localization is not possible see this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159638/pgfplots-import-data-from-table-with-comma-as-decimal-separator . Also if your question is a duplicate of that one please let us know so we can mark it. Because I think the scale problem is solved now isn't it?

Comment: The link you posted was about reading in comma decimal-separated values. I don't have those. 
I want the output scaling to be with commas. But then the 10^5 is placed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

After some trying and testing I found, that

```
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}
```

instead of

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
ticklabel style={% gilt für x und y
/pgf/number format/.cd,
use comma,
1000 sep={}
}}
```

solves the problem. Hope this helps for others.