# Drawing an histogram of the repartition of a data set

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, histogram, programming-tools

I have a dataset of marks (0 to 20), for example a `[2, 3, 7, 14, 15, ...]`

I would like to draw an histogram of the repartition of this dataset. What I mean is an histogram where on the `x`-axis are some ranges of marks (for instance: `0 to 1`, `1 to 2`, ..., `19 to 20`) and on the `y`-axis are the number of marks in this range.

For instance something like that:

[image]

The code of this image is produced by a Python program writing a `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0, ymax=6.2 ,
        ytick={0,2,...,6},
        minor y tick num = 0,
        %area style,
        width=10cm,
        height=4cm,
        axis lines*=left,
        bar width=0.6cm,
        y axis line style = {draw = none},
        tick align      = outside,
        tick pos        = left
        ]\addplot+[ybar interval, mark=no, fill=black!20, draw=black!40] coordinates{(6.0,2) (6.933333333333334,2) 
(6.933333333333334,1) (7.866666666666667,1) 
(7.866666666666667,1) (8.8,1) 
(8.8,2) (9.733333333333334,2) 
(9.733333333333334,6) (10.666666666666668,6) 
(10.666666666666668,3) (11.600000000000001,3) 
(11.6,5) (12.533333333333333,5) 
(12.533333333333333,6) (13.466666666666667,6) 
(13.466666666666667,4) (14.4,4) 
(14.4,2) (15.333333333333334,2) 
(15.333333333333334,4) (16.266666666666666,4) 
(16.266666666666666,3) (17.2,3) 
(17.2,0) (18.133333333333333,0) 
(18.133333333333333,2) (19.066666666666666,2) 
(19.066666666666666,1) (20.0,1) 
};
    \addplot+[ybar interval, mark=no, fill=black!70, draw=black!90] coordinates{(15.333333333333334,4)  (16.266666666666666,4) };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

## My question

I would like to know if it is possible to do it only with LaTeX (or LuaLaTeX, etc.). The dataset would be, for instance, in the following format (where `8,5` is the french notation of `8.5`):

```
8,5
13,5
6,5
8,5
10
8
5,5
2,5
5,5
7
20
12
18,5
5,5
9,5
3,5
0
7
7
5,5
10
3,5
7
14,5
7
10,5
16,5
10,5
6,5
8
14
8,5
2,5
5
9,5
8
10
9,5
9
8,5
4,5
5,5
```

I would prefer to stick to this format but any format produced automatically by Excel (`.csv`, etc.) can also be considered.

What tool would you use? Do you have any advise for such a "program"?

---

## edit

With the dataset given in example, the histogram should look like this image

[image]

Comment: You can use `/pgf/number format/read comma as period` to read data with a comma as decimal separator, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287984, or use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159644.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can accumulate the data points as follows. (Alternatives include stacked plots.)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{commadata.dat}
8,5
13,5
6,5
8,5
10
8
5,5
2,5
5,5
7
20
12
18,5
5,5
9,5
3,5
0
7
7
5,5
10
3,5
7
14,5
7
10,5
16,5
10,5
6,5
8
14
8,5
2,5
5
9,5
8
10
9,5
9
8,5
4,5
5,5
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{[index]#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread[/pgf/number format/read comma as period]{commadata.dat}\datatable
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\datatable}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numcols}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \edef\myxmax{0}%
  \foreach \nY in {1,...,\numrows}
  {\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\the\numexpr\nY-1}{0}{\Current}%
   \StrSubstitute{\Current}{,}{.}[\mytemp]
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{\mytemp+1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myxmax}{max(\myxmax,\myx)}
   \xdef\myxmax{\myxmax}
  }
  \foreach \X in {0,...,\myxmax}
  {\expandafter\xdef\csname mypile\X\endcsname{0}}
  \foreach \nY in {1,...,\numrows}
  {\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\the\numexpr\nY-1}{0}{\Current}%
   \StrSubstitute{\Current}{,}{.}[\mytemp]
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{\mytemp}%
   \edef\currentval{\csname mypile\myx\endcsname}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycur}{\currentval+1}
   \expandafter\xdef\csname mypile\myx\endcsname{\mycur}
  }

  \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0,% ymax=6.2,
        xmin=0,
        %ytick={0,2,...,6},
        minor y tick num = 0,
        %area style,
        width=10cm,
        height=4cm,
        axis lines*=left,
        %bar width=0.2cm,
        y axis line style = {draw = none},
        tick align      = outside,
        tick pos        = left
        ]
   \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\myxmax}{%
   \edef\currentval{\csname mypile#1\endcsname}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycur}{\currentval}
   \addplot[ybar, fill=black!20, draw=black!40] coordinates {(#1-0.5,\mycur)};
   }    
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**OLDER ANSWER**: One can read your data with `/pgf/number format/read comma as period`, as pointed out in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287984). In order to get the intervals of width 1, we only need `x expr=\coordindex`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{commadata.dat}
y
8,5
13,5
6,5
8,5
10
8
5,5
2,5
5,5
7
20
12
18,5
5,5
9,5
3,5
0
7
7
5,5
10
3,5
7
14,5
7
10,5
16,5
10,5
6,5
8
14
8,5
2,5
5
9,5
8
10
9,5
9
8,5
4,5
5,5
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0,% ymax=6.2,
        xmin=0,
        %ytick={0,2,...,6},
        minor y tick num = 0,
        %area style,
        width=10cm,
        height=4cm,
        axis lines*=left,
        %bar width=0.2cm,
        y axis line style = {draw = none},
        tick align      = outside,
        tick pos        = left
        ]
  \addplot+[ybar interval, mark=no, fill=black!20, draw=black!40] 
  table[y=y,x expr=\coordindex,/pgf/number format/read comma as period,col sep=tab] {commadata.dat};
  % \addplot+[ybar interval, mark=no, fill=black!70, draw=black!90] coordinates{(15.333333333333334,4)  (16.266666666666666,4) };
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! But, it is not the right histogram. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Colas How is that possible? Your data set starts with the three values `8,5`,
`13,5` and `6,5`, whereas the desired output shows a bar of height 1, a bar of height 0 and a bar of height 2. What am I missing? What is the prescription to draw the bars from the data? (BTW, you nee to use `ybar` rather than `ybar interval` to produce the histogram of the desired output.)

Comment: See the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: @Colas OK, I see. And in which bins should the integers go. E.g. `10` belongs in the bin from 9 to 10 or 10 to 11?

Comment: Thanks. I take 21 bins : 0 ≤ x < 1, ..., 19≤ x < 20, x = 20.

Comment: @Colas I added something that counts the points in the respective intervals.

Comment: Great! Thanks! 