# Computing the mean value in (La)TeX

Tags: pgfplots, programming

I have a list of marks included in a `.tex` document, with the `begin{filecontents*}` command.

So far, I draw a histogram of the frequencies of the marks.

**I would like to add the mean value.**

Can you help me? Here is my code so far, [adapted from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516953/8323)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{commadata.dat}
8,5
13,5
6,5
8,5
10
8
5,5
2,5
5,5
7
20
12
18,5
5,5
9,5
3,5
0
7
7
5,5
10
3,5
7
14,5
7
10,5
16,5
10,5
6,5
8
14
8,5
2,5
5
9,5
8
10
9,5
9
8,5
4,5
5,5
\end{filecontents*}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Layout %
%%%%%%%%%%
\def\myHMargin{0.85cm}
\def\myVMarginTop{7mm}
\def\myVMarginBottom{7mm}
\usepackage[hmargin={\myHMargin,\myHMargin},
            vmargin={\myVMarginTop,\myVMarginBottom},
            headsep=5mm,
            footskip=\dimexpr(\baselineskip+4mm),
            includefoot,
            includehead,
            twoside]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{[index]#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------



% grid style
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dotted,gray}}


\begin{center}

\fbox{Mean value : $\displaystyle\frac{\ ??? \ }{20}$}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread[/pgf/number format/read comma as period]{commadata.dat}\datatable
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\datatable}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numcols}{\pgfplotsretval}

%  \edef\myxmax{0}%
%  \foreach \nY in {1,...,\numrows}
%  {\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\the\numexpr\nY-1}{0}{\Current}%
%   \StrSubstitute{\Current}{,}{.}[\mytemp]
%   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{\mytemp}
%   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myxmax}{max(\myxmax,\myx)}
%   \xdef\myxmax{\myxmax}
%  }

  \edef\myxmax{20}
  \foreach \X in {0,...,\myxmax}
  {\expandafter\xdef\csname mypile\X\endcsname{0}}
  \foreach \nY in {1,...,\numrows}
  {\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\the\numexpr\nY-1}{0}{\Current}%
   \StrSubstitute{\Current}{,}{.}[\mytemp]
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{\mytemp}%
   \edef\currentval{\csname mypile\myx\endcsname}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycur}{\currentval+1}
   \expandafter\xdef\csname mypile\myx\endcsname{\mycur}
  }

  \begin{axis}[ymajorgrids,
        ymin=0,% ymax=6.2,
        xmin=-1,
        %ytick={0,2,...,6},
        xtick={0,1,...,20},
        xticklabels={\small $0$-$1$, \small $1$-$2$, \small $2$-$3$, \small $3$-$4$, \small $4$-$5$, \small $5$-$6$, \small $6$-$7$, \small $7$-$8$, \small $8$-$9$, \small $9$-$10$, \small $10$-$11$, \small $11$-$12$, \small 
        $12$-$13$, \small $13$-$14$, \small $14$-$15$, \small $15$-$16$, \small $16$-$17$, \small $17$-$18$, \small $18$-$19$, \small $19$-$20$, \small $\geq 20$},
        minor y tick num = 0,
        %area style,
        width=28cm,
        height=10cm,
        axis lines*=left,
        %bar width=0.2cm,
        y axis line style = {->},
        x axis line style = {->},
        tick align      = outside,
        tick pos        = left
        ]
   \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\myxmax}{%
   \edef\currentval{\csname mypile#1\endcsname}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycur}{\currentval}
   \addplot[ybar, fill=black!20, draw=black!40, ycomb, line width=8mm, color=blue!50] coordinates {(#1,\mycur)};
   }    
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{commadata.dat}
8,5
13,5
6,5
8,5
10
8
5,5
2,5
5,5
7
20
12
18,5
5,5
9,5
3,5
0
7
7
5,5
10
3,5
7
14,5
7
10,5
16,5
10,5
6,5
8
14
8,5
2,5
5
9,5
8
10
9,5
9
8,5
4,5
5,5
\end{filecontents*}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Layout %
%%%%%%%%%%
\def\myHMargin{0.85cm}
\def\myVMarginTop{7mm}
\def\myVMarginBottom{7mm}
\usepackage[hmargin={\myHMargin,\myHMargin},
            vmargin={\myVMarginTop,\myVMarginBottom},
            headsep=5mm,
            footskip=\dimexpr(\baselineskip+4mm),
            includefoot,
            includehead,
            twoside]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{[index]#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------



% grid style
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dotted,gray}}


\begin{center}

%\fbox{Mean value : $\displaystyle\frac{\ ??? \ }{20}$}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread[/pgf/number format/read comma as period]{commadata.dat}\datatable
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\datatable}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numcols}{\pgfplotsretval}

  \edef\myxmax{20}
  \foreach \X in {0,...,\myxmax}
  {\expandafter\xdef\csname mypile\X\endcsname{0}}
  \edef\Total{0}
  \foreach \nY in {1,...,\numrows}
  {\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\the\numexpr\nY-1}{0}{\Current}%
   \StrSubstitute{\Current}{,}{.}[\mytemp]
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{\mytemp}%
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\Total}{\Total+\myx}
   \xdef\Total{\Total}
   \edef\currentval{\csname mypile\myx\endcsname}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycur}{\currentval+1}
   \expandafter\xdef\csname mypile\myx\endcsname{\mycur}
  }
  \begin{axis}[ymajorgrids,
        ymin=0,% ymax=6.2,
        xmin=-1,
        %ytick={0,2,...,6},
        xtick={0,1,...,20},
        xticklabels={\small $0$-$1$, \small $1$-$2$, \small $2$-$3$, \small $3$-$4$, \small $4$-$5$, \small $5$-$6$, \small $6$-$7$, \small $7$-$8$, \small $8$-$9$, \small $9$-$10$, \small $10$-$11$, \small $11$-$12$, \small 
        $12$-$13$, \small $13$-$14$, \small $14$-$15$, \small $15$-$16$, \small $16$-$17$, \small $17$-$18$, \small $18$-$19$, \small $19$-$20$, \small $\geq 20$},
        minor y tick num = 0,
        %area style,
        width=28cm,
        height=10cm,
        axis lines*=left,
        %bar width=0.2cm,
        y axis line style = {->},
        x axis line style = {->},
        tick align      = outside,
        tick pos        = left,
        title={Mean value : $\pgfmathparse{\Total/\numrows}
        \displaystyle\frac{\Total}{\numrows}=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$},
        ]
   \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\myxmax}{%
   \edef\currentval{\csname mypile#1\endcsname}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycur}{\currentval}
   \addplot[ybar, fill=black!20, draw=black!40, ycomb, line width=8mm, color=blue!50] coordinates {(#1,\mycur)};
   }    
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you want the mean occupation number,

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{commadata.dat}
8,5
13,5
6,5
8,5
10
8
5,5
2,5
5,5
7
20
12
18,5
5,5
9,5
3,5
0
7
7
5,5
10
3,5
7
14,5
7
10,5
16,5
10,5
6,5
8
14
8,5
2,5
5
9,5
8
10
9,5
9
8,5
4,5
5,5
\end{filecontents*}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Layout %
%%%%%%%%%%
\def\myHMargin{0.85cm}
\def\myVMarginTop{7mm}
\def\myVMarginBottom{7mm}
\usepackage[hmargin={\myHMargin,\myHMargin},
            vmargin={\myVMarginTop,\myVMarginBottom},
            headsep=5mm,
            footskip=\dimexpr(\baselineskip+4mm),
            includefoot,
            includehead,
            twoside]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{[index]#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------



% grid style
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dotted,gray}}


\begin{center}

%\fbox{Mean value : $\displaystyle\frac{\ ??? \ }{20}$}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread[/pgf/number format/read comma as period]{commadata.dat}\datatable
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\datatable}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numcols}{\pgfplotsretval}

  \edef\myxmax{20}
  \foreach \X in {0,...,\myxmax}
  {\expandafter\xdef\csname mypile\X\endcsname{0}}
  \edef\Total{0}
  \foreach \nY in {1,...,\numrows}
  {\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\the\numexpr\nY-1}{0}{\Current}%
   \StrSubstitute{\Current}{,}{.}[\mytemp]
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{\mytemp}%
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\Total}{\Total+\myx}
   \xdef\Total{\Total}
   \edef\currentval{\csname mypile\myx\endcsname}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycur}{\currentval+1}
   \expandafter\xdef\csname mypile\myx\endcsname{\mycur}
  }
  \begin{axis}[ymajorgrids,
        ymin=0,% ymax=6.2,
        xmin=-1,xmax=21,
        %ytick={0,2,...,6},
        xtick={0,1,...,20},
        xticklabels={\small $0$-$1$, \small $1$-$2$, \small $2$-$3$, \small $3$-$4$, \small $4$-$5$, \small $5$-$6$, \small $6$-$7$, \small $7$-$8$, \small $8$-$9$, \small $9$-$10$, \small $10$-$11$, \small $11$-$12$, \small 
        $12$-$13$, \small $13$-$14$, \small $14$-$15$, \small $15$-$16$, \small $16$-$17$, \small $17$-$18$, \small $18$-$19$, \small $19$-$20$, \small $\geq 20$},
        minor y tick num = 0,
        %area style,
        width=28cm,
        height=10cm,
        axis lines*=left,
        %bar width=0.2cm,
        y axis line style = {->},
        x axis line style = {->},
        tick align      = outside,
        tick pos        = left,
%       title={Mean value : $\pgfmathparse{\Total/\numrows}
%       \displaystyle\frac{\Total}{\numrows}=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$},
        ]
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\Occ}{0}        
   \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\myxmax}{%
   \edef\currentval{\csname mypile#1\endcsname}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycur}{\currentval}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Occ}{\Occ+\currentval}
   \xdef\Occ{\Occ}
   \addplot[ybar, fill=black!20, draw=black!40, ycomb, line width=8mm, color=blue!50] coordinates {(#1,\mycur)};
   }    
  \end{axis}
  \node[draw,above] at (current axis.north) {Mean value :
      $\displaystyle\frac{\Occ}{20}$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Before I open a new question about that, do you know how I could shorten the "x-axis": the length after the last bar is very large. Thanks

Comment: @Colas For that you only need to set an appropriate `xmax`, e.g. `xmax=21`. Please see the lower plot in which the average occupation number gets computed. `xmax=21` works for the upper plot, too.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: Hi @Schrödinger's cat. I would like the mean value to be printed with the french formatting, for instance `12,3` instead of `12.3`. Do you know how to modify your code so that it does so? Thanks

Comment: @Colas This is very easy: use `use comma`. i.e. replace `title={Mean value : $\pgfmathparse{\Total/\numrows}
        \displaystyle\frac{\Total}{\numrows}=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$}` by `title={Mean value : $\pgfmathparse{\Total/\numrows}
        \displaystyle\frac{\Total}{\numrows}=\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{\pgfmathresult}$}`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it differently.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
8,5
13,5
6,5
8,5
10
8
5,5
2,5
5,5
7
20
12
18,5
5,5
9,5
3,5
0
7
7
5,5
10
3,5
7
14,5
7
10,5
16,5
10,5
6,5
8
14
8,5
2,5
5
9,5
8
10
9,5
9
8,5
4,5
5,5
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[varwidth=40cm,border=4]{standalone}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dotted,gray}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\readmarks}{mm}
 {% #1 = file name, #2 = upper limit
  \colas_readmarks:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getmarks}{m}
 {
  0\prop_item:Nn \l_colas_readmarks_prop { #1 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getaverage}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n
   {
    (0 \int_step_function:nN { #1 } \__colas_readmarks_add:n )/(#1)
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__colas_readmarks_add:n
 {
  +0\prop_item:Nn \l_colas_readmarks_prop { #1 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g__colas_readmarks_stream
\prop_new:N \l_colas_readmarks_prop
\tl_new:N \l__colas_readmarks_item_tl

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { Nxx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Ne }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \colas_readmarks:nn
 {
  \prop_clear:N \l_colas_readmarks_prop
  \ior_open:Nn \g__colas_readmarks_stream { #1 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g__colas_readmarks_stream 
   {
    \__colas_readmarks_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__colas_readmarks_item:nn
 {% #1 = upper limit, #2 = item
  \tl_set:Nn \l__colas_readmarks_item_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l__colas_readmarks_item_tl { , } { . }
  \prop_put:Nxx \l_colas_readmarks_prop
   {
    \fp_eval:n { \l__colas_readmarks_item_tl < #1 ? floor(\l__colas_readmarks_item_tl) : 20 }
   }
   {
    \int_eval:n
     {
      1 + 
      0\prop_item:Ne \l_colas_readmarks_prop
       {
        \fp_eval:n { \l__colas_readmarks_item_tl < #1 ? floor(\l__colas_readmarks_item_tl) : 20 }
       }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\readmarks{\jobname.dat}{20}

\centering

\fbox{Mean value: $\getaverage{20}$}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  ymajorgrids,
  ymin=0,
%  ymax=6.2,
  xmin=-1,
%  ytick={0,2,...,6},
  xtick={0,1,...,20},
  xticklabels={
    \small $0$-$1$, \small $1$-$2$, \small $2$-$3$, \small $3$-$4$,
    \small $4$-$5$, \small $5$-$6$, \small $6$-$7$, \small $7$-$8$,
    \small $8$-$9$, \small $9$-$10$, \small $10$-$11$, \small $11$-$12$,
    \small $12$-$13$, \small $13$-$14$, \small $14$-$15$, \small $15$-$16$,
    \small $16$-$17$, \small $17$-$18$, \small $18$-$19$, \small $19$-$20$,
    \small $\geq 20$
  },
  minor y tick num = 0,
%   area style,
   width=28cm,
   height=10cm,
   axis lines*=left,
%   bar width=0.2cm,
   y axis line style = {->},
   x axis line style = {->},
   tick align      = outside,
   tick pos        = left
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,20}{%
  \addplot[
    ybar,
    fill=black!20,
    draw=black!40,
    ycomb,
    line width=8mm,
    color=blue!50
  ] coordinates {(#1,\getmarks{#1})};
}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The file is read and a property list is populated. Then we can retrieve the values in a much simpler way.

[image]

Comment: I wish I could do programming in LaTeX as easily as I would do in Python for instance. What would you advise me? Try LuaLaTeX?

Comment: When I try to compile your file, I have an error: `./Notes_interrogation_9_2019_2020.tex:117: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \::e 
                
l.117 \readmarks{\jobname.dat}{20}`

Comment: Hi @egreg, it seems that your MWE is not compiling. When I try to compile it, I have the following error: `./bac_a_sable.tex:117: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \::e 
                
l.117 \readmarks{\jobname.dat}{20}`. I'm now looking more precisely at your answer because I would like the mean value to be printed with the french formatting, for instance `12,3` instead of `12.3`. Thanks

Comment: @Colas You have an outdated TeX system

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear if you want the mean frequency or just the mean of the x variable. For the second case:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
<<data,echo=F>>=
df <- read.csv(file="commadata.dat",head=F, dec=",", sep=";")
@

The mean is \(\frac{\Sexpr{sum(df$V1)}}{\Sexpr{length(df$V1)}}=
\Sexpr{sum(df$V1)/length(df$V1)}\)

\bigskip

<<histogran,echo=F,dev="tikz">>=
x <- round(mean(df$V1),2)
hist(df$V1, breaks=21,col="tan1",  xaxp  = c(0, 20, 20), ylim=c(0,8),
     main="", xlab="",ylab="")
arrows(x,7.8,x,0, length=0.15, col =4, code=1,lwd=2)
text(x,8,paste("$\\overline{\\mbox{x}}=$",x))
@

\end{document}
```