# pgf's 'read comma as period' doesn't work as expected with pgfplots and lualatex

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, locale

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287984/18401), `/pgf/number format/read comma as period` should be enough to plot data from data files which are using the comma as decimal separator instead of the period. But, as shown by the following MCE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data-periods.dat}
x y
1.5 1
2.5 10
3.5 100
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data-commas.dat}
x y
2,5 1
3,5 10
4,5 100
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot table [x=x,y=y]                                         {data-periods.dat} ;
  \addplot table [x=x,y=y,/pgf/number format/read comma as period] {data-commas.dat} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

it doesn't work when processed with `lualatex` (it works like a charm with `pdflatex` and `xelatex`), the second plot being dropped because of:

```
NOTE: coordinate (--,--,--) [--](was (2,5,1,--)   [--]) has been dropped because of a coordinate filter.
NOTE: coordinate (--,--,--) [--](was (3,5,10,--)  [--]) has been dropped because of a coordinate filter.
NOTE: coordinate (--,--,--) [--](was (4,5,100,--) [--]) has been dropped because of a coordinate filter.

Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away) on input line 36.
```

Am I missing something?

### Edit

It's worth pointing out that the issue doesn't arise with `tikz`'s `datavisualization` library: the following MCE compiles like a charm with lualatex (LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as line]
data [separator=\space] {
x y
0.5 0
1.5 1
2.5 1
3.5 0
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfset{/pgf/number format/read comma as period}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as line]
data [separator=\space] {
x y
0,5 0
1,5 1
2,5 1
3,5 0
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not get that in my TL23. I'll run the updater and test again.

Comment: It works fine under `pdflatex`, `xelatex` but under `lualatex` I get the same error. Perhaps you should list which engine you use

Comment: Indeed, I was running `lualatex`. I'll edit my question.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the issue doesn't arise with `tikz`'s `datavisualization` library (see question edited).

Comment: Under LuaTeX some math stuff is done by Lua, not TeX. I guess the Lua part lacks support for `/pgf/number format/read comma as period`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ But `lualatex` should then fail with `tikz`'s `datavisualization` library as well, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Manual for Package pgfplots (v1.18.1), sec. 6.3.1 "LUA" reads

> If you use `compat=1.12` (or newer) and compile your documents by means of `lualatex`, pgfplots activates its `lua backend`. This switch reduces the time to generate output files, especially for 3D plots.
>
> `/pgfplots/lua backend=true|false` (initially `true`)
>
> If `lua backend` is active and the document is processed by means of `lualatex`, `pgfplots` activates scalability and performance improvements which result in the same output as without it, but with less time and with a smarter memory management.

But as OP's example shown, `lua backend` doesn't always result in the same output as without it.

`lua backend` will load an un-documented tikz-pgf library `luamath`, which replaces `pgfmath` math expression parser with a lua-based new one. Unfortunately, this lua-based parser doesn't support `/pgf/number format/read comma as period`. `tikz` itself doesn't load `luamath` by default, hence it's less likely that the same problem is found in (simple or natural) `tikz` examples.

I've reported this to `pgf` see its [issue #1263](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1263).  Below is a patch copied from my comment under [`pgfplots` issue #452](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/452), which essentially reported the same problem as the current tex-sx question.

Please note that I know very little about `pgfplots` internals, hence the patch below is very specific to the case in hand. It's not a general solution to the root problem "`luamath` doesn't support `/pgf/number format/read comma as period`."

```tex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\begin{filecontents}[noheader,force]{data-periods.dat}
x y
1.5 1
2.5 10
3.5 100
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[noheader,force]{data-commas.dat}
x y
2,5 1
3,5 10
4,5 100
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfplots@LUA@survey@point{%
  \ifpgfmathparsenumber@comma@as@period
    % Assume each point is a single number without any math function calls. 
    % Only then is reading comma as period unambiguous.
    \edef\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{pgfplots.texSurveyPoint(%
      gsub("\pgfplots@current@point@x", ",", "."),%
      gsub("\pgfplots@current@point@y", ",", "."),%
      gsub("\pgfplots@current@point@z", ",", "."),%
      "\pgfplots@current@point@meta")}%
    \pgfplotsutil@directlua{%
      gsub = string.gsub
      \pgfplots@loc@TMPa
    }%
  \else
    \edef\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{pgfplots.texSurveyPoint(%
      "\pgfplots@current@point@x",%
      "\pgfplots@current@point@y",%
      "\pgfplots@current@point@z",%
      "\pgfplots@current@point@meta")}%
    \pgfplotsutil@directlua{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
  \fi
  % increase \pgfplots@current@point@coordindex:
  \advance\c@pgfplots@coordindex by1
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table [x=x,y=y]
      {data-periods.dat} ;
    \addplot table [x=x,y=y,/pgf/number format/read comma as period]
      {data-commas.dat} ;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]